# Save the annotation marks in flexpaper annotation document viewer

Tags: annotations, save, flexpaper

How to save the annotation marks  in flexpaper annotation document viewer?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

FlexPaper provides a JavaScript function called getMarkList:

```
marksArray = JSON.stringify($FlexPaper('documentViewer').getMarkList());
```

You can apply the annotations again using addMarks:

```
var initialMarks = JSON.parse(marksArray);
$FlexPaper('documentViewer').addMarks(initialMarks);
```

This works for the HTML5 version but I suspect it would also apply to the Flash and HTML versions.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I think I've found a bug in Flexpaper that prevents this from being useful (bug is in the Flash version, have not tested HTML version). If anyone has actually got this to work on Flash, please let me know!

Basically, `addMark()` is performing an unnecessary coordinate transformation which makes it impossible to put back in a mark that you have extracted in the same spot (this only seems to be the case for notes, drawings don't seem to have this issue).

Here's how to reproduce:

Go to http://devaldi.com/annotations/UK_Investment_Fund.php?ro=flash,html and open Chrome JS console. Enter these commands:

```
>> note = $FlexPaper('documentViewer').getMarkList()[2]
Object {width: 200, pageIndex: 1, height: 180, note: "The annotations plug-in allows both highlighting a…created↵↵Notes can be resized, moved and deleted.", id: "3AFE17A3-4977-3ECA-C468-70F2C40B81E8"…}

>> // Now try to add back in the same annotation
>> $FlexPaper('documentViewer').addMark(note)

>> // Notice that on the screen the note is in the wrong spot
>> // (not the same spot as the original one). Lets check the positioning

>> added_note = $FlexPaper('documentViewer').getMarkList()[6]

>> added_note.positionX
356.718192627824

>> note.positionX
-5.945303210463702
```

Answer (score 0):

The normalize/denormalization of positions should work fine as long as you set 'displayFormat' to 'html' as part of your object creation. The normalisation process basically adjusts X/Y/Width/Height so that the document is considered to be 1000 in height. The viewer then adjusts the positions when the annotations are being displayed if the document is different in height for flash or html. It also of course considers the proportions of the width/height of the document as part of this process.

All the best
Erik on the FlexPaper Team